# SqlBulkCopy - which database is causing the exception?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to copy a batch of records from MySQL to SQL Server.

After exactly 30 seconds, I get this

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

There's one 'Error' object inside the exception, with the following details:

```
Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
LineNumber: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure: 
Index #1
Message: The statement has been terminated.
LineNumber: 1
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure:
```

Here's the code

```
using (MySqlConnection sourceConnection = new MySqlConnection(AccManConnectionString)) {
sourceConnection.Open();
MySqlCommand commandSourceData = new MySqlCommand(string.Format(sql, VersionNum.ToString()), sourceConnection);
for (int i = 0; i < ParamNames.Length; i++)
{
    commandSourceData.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParamNames[i], SetIDList[i]);
}
MySqlDataReader reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();
using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(TimetableConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
    destinationConnection.Open();   
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "NetworkID";

        // Configure the batch sizes and timeouts (cofig code omitted)
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = batchSize;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = timeout;

        try
        {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE p SET p.Username = n.Username FROM NetworkID n INNER JOIN Person p ON n.PersonID = p.PersonID and n.VersionID = {0} where p.VersionID = {0}", VersionNum), destinationConnection);
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
        log.Error("Exception caught", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
        reader.Close();
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    log.Error("Exception caught", e);
    }
 }
}
```

I know there are plenty of timeout/batch size parameters I can (and have) experiment with. But my question is, from a coding point of view, is there any way of determining which database server is the one giving me problems?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the SqlClient namespace is a dead giveaway

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know ADO enough - thought it might call the MySql/SQLServer drivers *after* that point (or hidden from the stack in some mysterious way)

Comment: Is it possible that even though the namespace there suggests SQL server, because I'm using SQLBulkCopy is it still possible that the MySQL source database is causing the problem, by holding up the SQL Server side (and then the SQL Server side fails as a consequence? The reason I ask is my DBAs are looking at the query as it runs, and there's definately something strange at the MySQL end (takes 39 seconds to run from C#, when it only takes about 2 seconds using MySQL Workbench)

Comment: Difficult to say. If you have noticed this kind of slowdown on MySql side then this is a plausible reason for the Timeout on the Sql Server side waiting to receive data. In this case I would check the query text but also the parameters and their datatype passed with AddWithValue (it is a double sword, handy, but dangerous for performance [See this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) it is about Sql Server but I think that could be valid also for MySql)

Answer (score 1):

The timeout you are experiencing is likely to be influenced by the settting [SqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.bulkcopytimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has a default of 30 seconds.

As for determining where the problem lies, your best bet is to catch the [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if it contains any more details, but in your instance I believe it will be your code (the client) timing out.

The documentation on [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a good example of how to enumerate the errors contained in the exception.

**Update 1**

I can see you are using MySqlCommand, I'm guessing this is Devart, if so you haven't set a timeout on this command, for this one you'll need to use the syntax [CommandTimeout](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand~CommandTimeout.html).

```
MySqlCommand commandSourceData = new MySqlCommand(string.Format(sql, VersionNum.ToString()), sourceConnection);
commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = timeout;
```

You should also put one on your [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE p SET p.Username = n.Username FROM NetworkID n INNER JOIN Person p ON n.PersonID = p.PersonID and n.VersionID = {0} where p.VersionID = {0}", VersionNum), destinationConnection);
update.CommandTimeout = timeout;
```

**Update 2**

Just reading the documentation on [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and noticed the following:

> If multiple active result sets (MARS) is disabled, WriteToServer makes
>   the connection busy. If MARS is enabled, you can interleave calls to
>   WriteToServer with other commands in the same connection.

I'm not sure if you are using MARS, but, your code above is calling into SQL to do an update after the WriteToServer method, but before the BulkCopy is closed (via Using).  Can you try explicitly closing the SQLBulkCopy by calling close before the Update or move the Update outside of the Using statement for the BulkCopy.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll see if there's any more detail hidden in the exception as you suggest. I've experimented with BulkCopyTimeout and also BatchSize (plus various connection string settings too) but maybe just haven't found the sweet spot yet. Will report back...

Comment: Are you saying that you have tried changing BulkCopyTimeout and it doesn't stop it failing after 30 seconds?  If so I think it's time to post up some of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've set that timeout to 60 but the exception still happens after 30 seconds. I'll keep trying to find other timeout settings. Have also asked our DBA if there are any server-side settings they can modify.

Comment: ok, might be worth checking the MySql DB - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

Comment: I'm just trying it with the latest MySQL.Data.dll too in case there's a bug in the version I've been using

Comment: Nope, same problem with the latest driver. Have asked the DBAs to check that setting on the server though - thanks for the tip

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying it out now - well spotted (and so far... it's not timing out...!)

Comment: Those settings do increase the timeout, which is good. However, what we're seeing is that it just hangs for longer, before crashing out with the same error. Looking into it a bit more, that update statement seems to be taking 25 minutes to run so far. On an older version of the database it takes 4 seconds! So, we're busy trying to work out what has changed. Thanks for your advice so far - much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's being blocked, can you profile the database and check for blocks?

Comment: Just want to say I'm not ignoring this... I will update soon - we're doing a lot of investigating at the moment.